# Elastic Beanstalk reuse existing load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-load-balancer

Is it possible to reuse existing load balancer using elastic beanstalk?

Comment: hi, any updates on this? it is year after this question, have you found if already existing ALB could be associated with EB app? similar way as it works in ECS

Answer (score 14):

As far as I could manage the only way I could get this to work was as follows:

1. Create your environment as a single instance and not load balanced. You will
   find that EB creates an Auto Scaling group regardless.
2. Manually create a Target Group for the EB environment (in the EC2 console under Target Groups)
3. Assign the Target Group you just created to the Auto Scale group (in the EC2 console under Target Groups, click on the Auto Scale group and edit the details)
4. Add the Listeners for the Target Group to the desired ALB
5. Done

Managing scaling has to be done on the Auto Scale group directly as it remains disabled on the EB console.

Changing configurations and updating the application works and pushes to all instances.

I haven't tested upgrading the OS but I assume that it will work without issue as it won't likely rebuild the Auto Scaling group

Rebuilding the environment works but as the Auto Scale group gets rebuilt you need to reset the Target Group and auto-scaling configuration on it manually.

Update: I've been running several clients with this setup without issue for over a year.

Comment: Marc, have you encountered issues with server upgrades? Or have you found a way to "attach" the Target Group to the autoscaling group to avoid this? See: https://serverfault.com/questions/1000783/application-load-balancer-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk-target-group

Comment: Hi Ben. No, I've not had any issues at all and actually run auto-upgrades on the environments. I'm not sure how the setup in the severfault was done but I've never experienced that issue at all over the last couple of years.

Answer (score 11):

AWS now supports [sharing of an Application Load Balancer among Elastic Beanstalk environments.](https://aws.amazon.com/tw/about-aws/whats-new/2020/09/aws-elastic-beanstalk-supports-sharing-application-load-balancer-elastic-beanstalk-environments/)

However, this can only be done during environment creation. Here're [the steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-alb-shared.html#environments-cfg-alb-shared-console) to use a shared load balancer.

> 1. Open the [Elastic Beanstalk console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/home), and in the **Regions** list, select your AWS Region.
> 2. In the navigation pane, choose **Environments**.
> 3. Choose [Create a new environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-create-wizard.html) to start creating your environment.
> 4. On the wizard's main page, before choosing **Create environment**, choose **Configure more options**.
> 5. Choose the **High availability** configuration preset.
>
>    Alternatively, in the **Capacity** configuration category, configure a **Load balanced** environment type. For details, see [Capacity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-create-wizard.html#environments-create-wizard-capacity).
> 6. In the **Load balancer** configuration category, choose **Edit**.
> 7. Select the **Application Load Balancer** option, if it isn't already selected, and then select the **Shared** option.
>
> [image]
>
> 8. Make any shared Application Load Balancer configuration changes that your environment requires.
> 9. Choose **Save**, and then make any other configuration changes that your environment requires.
> 10. Choose **Create environment**.

After doing the above steps, Elastic Beanstalk creates rules inside the shared load balancer.

The rules forward requests based on the `Host` header.

In the end, your shared load balancer will look like this:

[image]

If you want to modify the current EB environment to use shared ALB, I  recommend the following steps:

1. Use [`eb config get <saved_configuration_name>`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-config.html) to download the current configuration of your environment.
2. Modify the configuration on your local computer.
3. Run `eb config put <modified_configuration_name>` to upload the configuration file to Elastic Beanstalk.
4. Use the modified saved configuration to launch a new environment to replace the old environment.

Comment: Updating the Saved Configuration is not going to help updating the existing environment to a shared ELB. The way i was able to manage updating an existing environment is as follows:
`1. Create a AN ALB and Target Group

1.a Create a Temp Elasticbeanstalk Environment

2. Route traffic to Temp Elasticbeanstalk Environment with Shared Loadbalancer

3. Delete the Original Elasticberanstalk Environment

4. Create the Original Elasticbeanstalk Environment with Shared Loadbalancer

5. Route traffic to Original Elasticbeanstalk Environment from Step 4.

6. Delete the Temp Environment`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible. Elastic beanstalk works on its on set of resources, like ASG, Security group and LB's etc. Sharing them with other components may cause unwanted changes to the components, that may take the system down. 
However, In my opinion, you should be able to add machines to EB load balancer once its created, however you will be in trouble when you terminate/recreate the application.