# Automatically re-register instance to target group on SHARED Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-application-load-balancer

[image]

Above you can se an ilustration of my aws environment. Maybe this will help ilustrate the problem.

I have a DEV environment with multiple Beanstalk projects being managed by one Shared Application Load Balancer.

It works great pointing the listeners to each target groups BUT

IF I Rebuild an environment or by any chance AWS kills one of my instances I have to manually re-register that new instance to the respective target group.

Is that any way to do it automatically? I've tried autoscalling groups with no success.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39875909

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you already found a solution but just in case you didn't.
I had this same issue and the answer was indeed the Auto-Scaling groups.

After you configure and create the EB envinronment with the shared load balancer. An Auto-Scaling group will be automatically created for this envinronment, this is where you add your custom target group, you add it to your Auto-Scaling group on the **Load Balancing** tab under **Load balancer target groups**

I haven't found a way to create a custom Auto-scaling group and assign it before hand so Elastic Beanstalk doesn't create one automatically. But adding your custom target group to the Auto-Scaling group that is created by EB has worked without issues for all my projects.

TL;DR:

1. Create your EB environment (Shared load Balancer configuration)
2. Create your custom target group
3. Add it to the Auto-Scaling group that was automatically generated when you created your EB Environment.
4. Remove the automatically generated target group that will be on the Auto-Scaling group, it's not needed anymore.